How to compile and install PaPs software from Github onto LMDE 6?
I intend to install PaPs software from Github onto LMDE6. The webpage https://github.com/dov/paps/blob/master/INSTALL.md indicates dependencies, all of which are installed on the target system. I have downloaded the zip archive from https://github.com/dov/paps/archive/refs/heads/master.zip, and I have extracted it on the target system as '/home/user/paps-master'. The webpage https://github.com/dov/paps/blob/master/INSTALL indicates that "the shell command './configure && make && make install' should configure, build, and install this package." Here is what I have tried:
user@host:~/paps-master$ ls -lh ./
total 136K
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  12K May 26 20:35 acinclude.m4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   38 May 26 20:35 AUTHORS
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  173 May 26 20:35 autogen.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 6.9K May 26 20:35 ChangeLog
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1019 May 26 20:35 configure.ac
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  25K May 26 20:35 COPYING.LIB
drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K May 26 20:35 examples
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 6.9K May 26 20:35 git.mk
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  16K May 26 20:35 INSTALL
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  236 May 26 20:35 INSTALL.md
drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K May 26 20:35 m4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1.4K May 26 20:35 Makefile.am
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2.2K May 26 20:35 meson.build
drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K May 26 20:35 misc
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1.1K May 26 20:35 NEWS
drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K May 26 20:35 po
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   15 May 26 20:35 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1.9K May 26 20:35 README.md
drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K May 26 20:35 scripts
drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K May 26 20:35 src
drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K May 26 20:35 subprojects

user@host:~/paps-master$ ./configure && make && make install
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

user@host:~/paps-master$ sh autogen.sh
Copying file po/Makefile.in.in

Please add the files
  codeset.m4 gettext.m4 glibc21.m4 iconv.m4 isc-posix.m4 lcmessage.m4
  progtest.m4
from the /usr/share/aclocal directory to your autoconf macro directory
or directly to your aclocal.m4 file.
You will also need config.guess and config.sub, which you can get from
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/.

autogen.sh: 5: intltoolize: not found
autogen.sh: 7: autoreconf: not found
autogen.sh: 8: ./configure: not found

Obviously unsuccessful. Here is the question: what must I do now in order to achieve an error free compilation and installation? I should mention that https://github.com/dov/paps/blob/master/INSTALL.md indicates "Installation instructions \n paps is preferably compiled with meson." and "Compilation \n meson build ; cd build && ninja", but I don't know what any of that means.
